# HttpRuntime in VisualStudio UnitTest

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Can I access `HttpRuntime` in my unit Test method. When I try to access every time it shows HttpRuntime does not exist in the current context. In my target method which I do want to test accessing a Cache variable

```
   HttpRuntime.Cache[key];
```

Is it possible ? or am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an HttpContext inside your unit test with a SimpleWorkerRequest object.

```
TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
HttpWorkerRequest httpRequest = new SimpleWorkerRequest("virtualDir", "physicalDir", "page", "", writer);
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(httpRequest);
HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] = some value..
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to refactor your target method to not access HttpRuntime directly, but instead to pass that information as a parameter or have it talk to an interface that wraps the HttpRuntime.  That way you can break the dependency on HttpRuntime and make things much easier to test.